# HTTP Live streaming iOS not refreshing the index .m3u8 file

Tags: ios, apache2, ffmpeg, playlist, http-streaming

I searched all similar questions on StackOverflow, but found none to answer my problem.

I am trying to stream some movies from my Linux computer (openSuSE 12.1) to my iPad. I convert them with ffmpeg, segment them with my own segmenter, place them in the www folder of my apache2 server and also place inside the .m3u8 playlist. Til here - all is ok!

I start playing the movie (HTML page with  tag) and it plays nicely, but only the first five segments, which have been loaded with the first load of the playlist. The HTML page (the browser, or the player - no idea) does not refresh (re-download) the playlist from the server.  Here is what my .m3u8 playlist file looks like:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:19
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:8

#EXTINF:8,
http://192.168.1.4/segment_19.ts
#EXTINF:8,
http://192.168.1.4/segment_20.ts
#EXTINF:8,
http://192.168.1.4/segment_21.ts
#EXTINF:8,
http://192.168.1.4/segment_22.ts
#EXTINF:8,
http://192.168.1.4/segment_23.ts
```

Segments are in the same folder as the playlist file, segments are correctly encoded (because I can see at least the first five ones :D). I also watch the access_log from the apache server and I see the first load of the playlist, then the consequent load of all 5 segments and it stops till there. It doesn't even try to further refresh the m3u8 file.

If it matters - iOS 5.0, iPad 2, Wi-Fi version only, not jailbroken

Ideas? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's only an idea, but what's the value of the Expires HTTP header when the playlist.m3u8 file is requested? Perhaps the user-agent is caching it?

Comment: Hi, good idea. I checked the httpd.conf file and all includes for Expire settings. There were none. So I exclusively set:
    ExpireByDefault "now"

So now it should always expire normally.
Because of this input from you, I decided to check the communication with WireShark. Here are my observations:
1) it fetches first my playlist with partial data; the condition is: if-modified-after, which means it checks for changes;
2) server sends the file, because it has been changed (first download :) )
3) iPad downloads all the ts files and stops
4) no more queries from the iPad ...

Ideas?

Comment: To rule out the iPad try watching the HLS with a nightly version of VLC player that supports it. Open the messages window to see if VLC is correctly re-reading the playlist file. If it works with VLC, then it's something to do with the iPad.
Some of the VLC nightlies are broken, so you may want to try the client here that definitely works - http://demo.anevia.com:8080/ott/vlc.php

Answer (score 1):

player(platform) will update m3u8 file automatic.
Not need http Expires setting in ios and android.
you can view access log of httpserver.